# Convert scanned pdf to .txt files using tesseract

Tags: tesseract

I have to convert a `.pdf` file containing scanned images into `.txt` files. The `tesseract ocr` converts only images to `.txt`, but I need to first extract the `.tif` images and *then* convert it. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use Imagemagick:

```
convert -density 600 input.pdf output.tif
```

Density is in DPI, from my experience 600 DPI works the best.

Comment: Can convert command be used to produce multiple output files? please help me with the usage of it.

Comment: @GaneshNannaware Yes, it can. Put `%04d` in the name of the output file and see how it works.